# Chessboard by dominoes in Discrete Math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question looks like obvious but I could not find the answer.

In how many ways can you cover a 2×n chessboard by dominoes?

Comment: Answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1100/25554) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79276/inductive-riddles-for-homework)

Comment: Is the answer n vertical and 2 times (n-1) horizontal ways to cover it?

Comment: Why don't you try it for small chessboards, say $2×1$, then $2×2, 2×3, 2×4,$ and $2×5$, and see how many ways you can find in each case.  That will give you some data that you can use to check any theories you have about how many ways there are in general. It may also give you some ideas about how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  set up a recurrence.  A $2 \times n$ board can have a vertical domino on the right, or a pair of horizontal dominoes on the right.